# Yii2 RBAC database explanation

Tags: php, yii2

I'm new to Yii2. I'm now working on RBAC but I don't understand the Database.
In table `auth_rule` and `auth_item` there is a field `data`. I check in the document they said "The additional data associated with this item" What does it mean? Where does it be use? Can please any one give me an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that is used anywhere. I personally use that field to misc info about the item (like in what module it is used so I may group them, what controller it is used for etc). basically just info stuff. You can just leave it empty if you do not want to use it.